# Issue installing igraph library

Tags: r, igraph, gfortran

I have been trying to install the `igraph` library in Ubuntu 20 but I get this error every time I try.

```
gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -g -O2  -c vendor/arpack/dgetv0.f -o vendor/arpack/dgetv0.o
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-call-libc-early-init.c: 37: _dl_call_libc_early_init: Assertion `sym != NULL' failed!
make: *** [/opt/R/4.2.2/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:192: vendor/arpack/dgetv0.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘igraph’
* removing ‘/home/ajaimes/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/igraph’
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/tmp/Rtmp8AlBTM/file24591376be44/igraph_1.4.99.9024.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

I think it's an issue with the fortran compiler because I got the same error with other libraries such as `mclust`:

```
gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fpic  -g -O2  -c dmvnorm.f -o dmvnorm.o
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-call-libc-early-init.c: 37: _dl_call_libc_early_init: Assertion `sym != NULL' failed!
make: *** [/opt/R/4.2.2/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:192: dmvnorm.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mclust’
```

I have gfortran installed on my machine: (`gfortran --version`)

```
GNU Fortran (Homebrew GCC 12.2.0) 12.2.0
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

My gcc version is: (`gcc --version`)

```
gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Mi session info is:

```
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=es_MX.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=es_MX.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=es_MX.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=es_MX.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=es_MX.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=es_MX.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=es_MX.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.2.2 tools_4.2.2
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

I tried also to install the `igraph` library directly from GitHub using `devtools` package `devtools::install_github("igraph/rigraph")` but also it didn't work. I saw this messages I think they could be related to the error:

```
checking whether the compiler supports GNU Fortran... no
checking whether gfortran accepts -g... no
```

**Solution**

As @VladimirFГероямслава pointed out, the problem was due to using homebrew in Ubuntu. Uninstalling homebrew fixed the problem. To uninstall [homebrew](https://blog.eldernode.com/install-and-uninstall-homebrew-on-ubuntu/)

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"
```

Comment: Your gcc and gfortran versions do not match. Although that may not always matter, it is really best to use one complete distribution of GCC (GNU compiler Collection). Why do ypu even use homebrew for Ubuntu? Gfortran is available in the normal repositories together with the respective versions of gcc and g++. Is your gfortran even able to compile a simple Hello world program that can be succesfuly run? Is there any log file with more details?

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава You are absolutely right, I removed homebrew and it fixed the issue. Thaks a lot!